# How trustworthy is Google API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

im currently learning Python and Im looking into writing a few tools that utilizes Google API so i can manipulate Google Sheets. But im wondering how "stable" it is.

My understanding is that they recently updated to v4 of their API for Google Sheets. Which means there were 3 versions before that.

How often do they change up/update their APIs? Is it safe to be writing something with their v4 API? I fear that we would have to constantly update due to changes they have made...

Comment: API updates typically add/fix features, not completely remove functional code. There's been more than 20 versions of Android SDK, for example, but the core functions still work fine and the rest should be well documented about what is changed

Comment: Huh it's probably as safe as for any API, service, language or platform… Maybe little more given the number of users Google API has and the stability of Google as a company, but if you consider how fast they can decide to totally shut down a service (like, say, Google Reader at the time), in the end, you can never really know… So sure, better to start with the latest version, but nobody could tell you how long it will last… It's a risk we all face everyday with all our technology choices…

Comment: @cricket_007 While that may be true for some SDK's, the google api changes have always been completely incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when an API is updated, the previous version remains available for a while (in a *deprecated* state). Currently, Google Spreadsheets API v3 is still available according to the [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/); however, it is deprecated, meaning usage is discouraged, unsupported, and will not be available in the future.

Additionally, there's a [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration) available, so even if the API does get updated, moving to the latest version shouldn't be too difficult. Additionally, as @cricket_007 mentioned, API updates generally don't change core features much.